# My magento website page is too long after fresh install

Tags: html, css, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

There's a lot of blank space at the bottom of my page - **http://htsmagento.nubis.eu/**?

I've been through the CSS lots looking for min-height type attributes but can't find any that would be causing this.

Any ideas what I can do to reduce that blank space at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the top menu.
There are a lot of subcategories in most of the menu items but this is the longest:

```
installation->rohre-fittinge->stahlrohr-schwarz
```

And for some reason unknown to me yet, the sub-menu items in Magento do not have `display:none` when they are not visible. They have `left: -10000px;`. This moves the menu items outside the visible area but their height is still taken into considaration.  See css class `#nav ul`. Maybe you can do something with that.
**[EDIT]**
Anyway...even if you manage to fix this you should rethink the category structure. It's not really user friendly to have a lot of sub-items. It's kind of hard to follow for the customer.
I would leave only the first 2 levels in the menu, and let the customer get to the rest of the categories by using the layered navigation. This approach will also speed up your website a little.
But this is just my opinion...you can ignore me.

Comment: Removed my answer, this one seems to explain it better +1

Comment: Thanks Marius. Your answer is the best. I managed to see the problem with your help. I will solve the problem right now.

Comment: +1 @Marius, really good explanation with clear and transparent solution and also find very quickly. so from my side no need to add new answer. good luck..

Comment: @user2694011. after you solve the issue maybe you can add a comment or edit my answer, or add a new one explaining what you did. I'm sure there will be others out there with this issue.

Comment: @Marius Sure I will post the explanation. See you